# Setup a Laravel existing project

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to install an existing Laravel project by running a "composer install" command but i'm getting the following errors :

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Symfony\Thanks\Command\ThanksCommand' not found in /home/lyes/Documents/AppStage/vendor/symfony/thanks/src/Thanks.php:58
```

Stack trace:

```
 #0 /usr/share/php/Composer/Plugin/PluginManager.php(236): Symfony\Thanks\Thanks->activate(Object(Composer\Composer), Object(Composer\IO\ConsoleIO))
    #1 /usr/share/php/Composer/Plugin/PluginManager.php(205): Composer\Plugin\PluginManager->addPlugin(Object(Symfony\Thanks\Thanks))
    #2 /usr/share/php/Composer/Plugin/PluginManager.php(261): Composer\Plugin\PluginManager->registerPackage(Object(Composer\Package\CompletePackage))
    #3 /usr/share/php/Composer/Plugin/PluginManager.php(76): Composer\Plugin\PluginManager->loadRepository(Object(Composer\Repository\InstalledFilesystemRepository))
    #4 /usr/share/php/Composer/Factory.php(384): Composer\Plugin\PluginManager->loadInstalledPlugins()
    #5 /usr/share/php/Composer/Factory.php(576): Composer\Factory->createComposer(Object(Composer\IO\ConsoleIO), Array, false)
    #6 /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php(332): C in /home/lyes/Documents/AppStage/vendor/symfony/thanks/src/Thanks.php on line 58

    Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Symfony\Thanks\Command\ThanksCommand' not found in /home/lyes/Documents/AppStage/vendor/symfony/thanks/src/Thanks.php:58
    Stack trace:
    #0 /usr/share/php/Composer/Plugin/PluginManager.php(236): Symfony\Thanks\Thanks->activate(Object(Composer\Composer), Object(Composer\IO\ConsoleIO))
    #1 /usr/share/php/Composer/Plugin/PluginManager.php(205): Composer\Plugin\PluginManager->addPlugin(Object(Symfony\Thanks\Thanks))
    #2 /usr/share/php/Composer/Plugin/PluginManager.php(261): Composer\Plugin\PluginManager->registerPackage(Object(Composer\Package\CompletePackage))
    #3 /usr/share/php/Composer/Plugin/PluginManager.php(76): Composer\Plugin\PluginManager->loadRepository(Object(Composer\Repository\InstalledFilesystemRepository))
    #4 /usr/share/php/Composer/Factory.php(384): Composer\Plugin\PluginManager->loadInstalledPlugins()
    #5 /usr/share/php/Composer/Factory.php(576): Composer\Factory->createComposer(Object(Composer\IO\ConsoleIO), Array, false)
    #6 /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php(332): C in /home/lyes/Documents/AppStage/vendor/symfony/thanks/src/Thanks.php on line 58
```

Can anyone help me, I am really overwhelmed

Answer (score 1):

Just delete `vendor` folder and than run `composer update` command

Answer (score 0):

Try using **composer update** and **composer dump-autoload** command

Answer (score 0):

When you run `composer install` it will look for a lock file and install whatever is contained in it. Check if your `composer.lock` or run `composer update` command

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

- Remove the `vendor` folder if already there
- Delete the `composer.lock` file
- Run `composer install` command in the terminal.